# How to get localized name of Known Folder?

Tags: c#, winapi

How can one get localized name of virtual Known Folder (such as This Computer, Control Panel etc.)?

Eg. for PL-pl they would be, respectively "Ten komputer", "Panel sterowania".

---

As suggested, I tried to use `IKnownFolder` from Shell32. There's a 3rd party ready-to-use implementation of these APIs, WinAPICodePack. Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Add from nuget: WindowsAPICodePack-Shell

        foreach (var folder in KnownFolders.All)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Canonical name: {folder.CanonicalName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tPath exists: {folder.PathExists}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tLocalized name: {folder.LocalizedName}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, mentioned "This Computer" and "Control Panel" entries does not have localized name.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160208-00/?p=93001 but you are looking for the pszLocalizedName field

Comment: Actually I guess from reading the docs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773325(v=vs.85).aspx that you'll have to read the name out of desktop.ini, because it is subject to change

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: perhaps GetFolderDefinition does that for you?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, how can I access that implementation from C#?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No it doesn't

Comment: @Spook Do some web search, there is sample code out there. At this point, having directed you to the pertinent interfaces, this just becomes an issue of how to access COM interfaces from C#. Well, that's already a well covered subject.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Actually, there's already an implementation for that - WinApiCodePack (available from Nuget). However, still this API doesn't provide localized names for mentioned "This Computer" and "Control Panel".

Comment: I think you are going to need to do a bit more work to get those.  My feeling is that you need to read the desktop.ini file out of the folder, and read the value of LocalizedResourceName from the .ShellClassInfo section. I think that's what the documentation tells you to do. Why don't you do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'd gladly do so if I only knew, where is `desktop.ini` for "This Computer" and "Control Panel" placed :) For existing folders I'm already extracting this resource from mentioned file.

Comment: Are we over thinking this. Don't you just want the display name of the actual folder?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, From what I know, there is no physical folder for "This Computer" or "Control panel". They're virtual, so I cannot display their names (apart from fact, that even if I could, they - mostly likely - wouldn't be localized).

Comment: That's not what I meant. The folder has a display name. Use that. RbMm's answer demonstrates, albeit using CSIDLs rather than known folder ids.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - really i use both CSIDLs and known folder ids in code. simply known folder ids exist begin form Vista only - so will be not work on xp. but begin from vista result will be the same ( system convert CSIDL to KNOWNFOLDERID if use `SHGetFolderLocation`

Comment: but main point - use `IShellItem::GetDisplayName` for got localized name. however exist different way how get  IShellItem for folder

Comment: @RbMm I was referring to the original versions of your answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, you right ) then i add version for vista too. however from msdn - "Note  As of Windows Vista, this function is merely a wrapper for SHGetKnownFolderIDList. The CSIDL value is translated to its associated KNOWNFOLDERID and SHGetKnownFolderIDList is called"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** .NET solution on the bottom.

---

you need got [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) interface for your folder and call [`IShellItem::GetDisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761140(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762544(v=vs.85).aspx)

> In UI this name is generally ideal for display to the user.

this return localized names

code in c++ can be like this

```
HRESULT GetKnownFolderName(int csidl, PWSTR* ppszName)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;

    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderLocation(0, csidl, 0, 0, &pidl);

    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        IShellItem* pItem;

        hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pItem));

        ILFree(pidl);

        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, ppszName);

            pItem->Release();
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

void testDN()
{
    if (0 <= CoInitialize(0))
    {
        PWSTR szName;
        // CSIDL_CONTROLS - for "Control Panel"
        // CSIDL_DRIVES - for "My Computer"
        if (S_OK == GetKnownFolderName(CSIDL_DRIVES, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

---

also if we running only on Vista+ we can use [`SHGetKnownFolderIDList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762187(v=vs.85).aspx) instead [`SHGetFolderLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762180(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`FOLDERID_ComputerFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) in place [`CSIDL_DRIVES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx) or we can get (or already have) [`IKnownFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761768(v=vs.85).aspx) interface first and then got [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx)  from it by [`IKnownFolder::GetShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761766(v=vs.85).aspx) - so yet two alternative variants begin from vista:

```
HRESULT GetKnownFolderName(IKnownFolder* kf, PWSTR* ppszName)
{
    IShellItem* psi;

    HRESULT hr = kf->GetShellItem(KF_FLAG_DEFAULT_PATH, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi));

    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        hr = psi->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, ppszName);

        psi->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT GetKnownFolderNameVista2(REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid, PWSTR* ppszName)
{
    IKnownFolderManager* mgr;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(KnownFolderManager), 0, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mgr));

    if (0 <= hr)
    {
        IKnownFolder* kf;

        hr = mgr->GetFolder(rfid, &kf);

        mgr->Release();

        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            hr = GetKnownFolderName(kf, ppszName);
            kf->Release();
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT GetKnownFolderNameVista(REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid, PWSTR* ppszName)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;

    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderIDList(rfid, KF_FLAG_NO_ALIAS, 0, &pidl);

    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        IShellItem* pItem;

        hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pItem));

        ILFree(pidl);

        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, ppszName);

            pItem->Release();
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

void testDN()
{
    if (0 <= CoInitialize(0))
    {
        PWSTR szName;
        if (S_OK == GetKnownFolderNameVista(FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        if (S_OK == GetKnownFolderNameVista2(FOLDERID_ComputerFolder, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

---

else one way - use [`IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775071(v=vs.85).aspx) with this code will be look like

```
HRESULT GetKnownFolderName(int csidl, PWSTR* ppszName)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;

    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderLocation(0, csidl, 0, 0, &pidl);

    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        IShellFolder* psf;
        PCUITEMID_CHILD pidlLast;

        hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psf), &pidlLast);

        if (S_OK == hr)
        {
            STRRET str;
            hr = psf->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlLast, SHGDN_NORMAL, &str);
            psf->Release();

            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                str.uType == STRRET_WSTR ? *ppszName = str.pOleStr, S_OK : hr = E_FAIL;
            }
        }
    }

    return hr;
}

void testDN()
{
    if (0 <= CoInitialize(0))
    {
        PWSTR szName;
        if (S_OK == GetKnownFolderName(CSIDL_DRIVES, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        if (S_OK == GetKnownFolderName(CSIDL_CONTROLS, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

---

You can use [WinApiCodePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) library (download from Nuget), which provides .NET implementation of several of mentioned before APIs. Sample code would look like following:

```
private static string GenerateLocalizedName(IKnownFolder shellFolder)
{
    // Attempt to obtain localized name of folder

    // 1. Directly from KnownFolder
    string localizedName = shellFolder.LocalizedName;

    // 2. From ShellObject (this solves This Computer and Control Panel issue)
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedName))
        localizedName = (shellFolder as ShellObject)?.Name;

    // 3. If folder is not virtual, use its localized name from desktop.ini
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedName) && Directory.Exists(shellFolder.Path))
    {
        try
        {
            localizedName = WinApiInterop.GetLocalizedName(shellFolder.Path);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Intentionally left empty
        }
    }

    // 4. If folder is not virtual, use its filename
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedName) && Directory.Exists(shellFolder.Path))
        localizedName = Path.GetFileName(shellFolder.Path);

    // 5. If everything else fails, use its canonicalName (eg. MyComputerFolder)
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedName))
        localizedName = shellFolder.CanonicalName;

    return localizedName;
}

private void LoadShellFolders()
{
    foreach (var shellFolder in KnownFolders.All)
    {
        string localizedName = GenerateLocalizedName(shellFolder);

        string comment = shellFolder.PathExists ? shellFolder.Path : $"shell:{shellFolder.CanonicalName}";

        infos.Add(new ShellFolderInfo(shellFolder.CanonicalName,
            localizedName,
            comment,
            shellFolder.CanonicalName,
            shellFolder.PathExists ? shellFolder.Path : null));
    }
}
```

Also, the WinApiInterop class, which resolves localized strings from desktop.ini:

```
static class WinApiInterop
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int SHGetLocalizedName(string pszPath, StringBuilder pszResModule, ref int cch, out int pidsRes);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadStringW", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hModule, int resourceID, StringBuilder resourceValue, int len);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryExW")]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

    internal const uint DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001;
    internal const uint LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern int FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExpandEnvironmentStringsW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern uint ExpandEnvironmentStrings(string lpSrc, StringBuilder lpDst, int nSize);

    public static string GetFullPath(string path)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);

        ExpandEnvironmentStrings(path, sb, sb.Capacity);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetLocalizedName(string path)
    {
        StringBuilder resourcePath = new StringBuilder(1024);
        StringBuilder localizedName = new StringBuilder(1024);
        int len, id;
        len = resourcePath.Capacity;

        if (SHGetLocalizedName(path, resourcePath, ref len, out id) == 0)
        {               
            ExpandEnvironmentStrings(resourcePath.ToString(), resourcePath, resourcePath.Capacity);
            IntPtr hMod = LoadLibraryEx(resourcePath.ToString(), IntPtr.Zero, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
            if (hMod != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (LoadString(hMod, id, localizedName, localizedName.Capacity) != 0)
                {
                    return localizedName.ToString();
                }
                FreeLibrary(hMod);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `S_OK` is one of many success codes in COM. If you want to check for success, use the [SUCCEEDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197.aspx) (or [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx)) macro.

Comment: 0 <= hr is also very opaque. As is the use of 0 rather than NULL.

Comment: may be how you say and more correct, however COM not sufficiently clear in this. 
i use `(hr == S_OK)` where in MSDN direct write : `If this method succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.` for general - `As per the COM specification, a result of zero indicates success and a nonzero result indicates failure` and `A simple check for zero or nonzero is adequate.` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688560(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: "many success codes in COM" - `S_FALSE` and what else ? (if you not mean all `>= 0` ). usual when function (method) can return `S_FALSE` direct documented as in case `CoInitialize`

Comment: A library can define **any** success code. The common [success codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919477.aspx) in Windows are `S_OK`, `S_FALSE`, and `S_TRUE`. Since COM is late-bound, you could be linking to an implementation, that doesn't follow the documentation you are reading today. Using the `SUCCEEDED` and `FAILED` macros is the safe way to implement error checking in COM.

Comment: @IInspectable - unlike `NTSTATUS` with nt-api, `HRESULT` values not sufficiently clear in this. even `S_FALSE` success or not code, what data(interface returned on it 0 or !=0) exist different cases. however what I paste also from MSDN - `A simple check for zero or nonzero is adequate` and `As per the COM specification, a result of zero indicates success and a nonzero result indicates failure.` . but when `S_FALSE` returned by `CoInitialize` - this is special documented and not failure. I use not custom 3-rd party interfaces but documented API(interfaces)

Comment: and here clear write - `If this method succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.` - "A library can define any success code" - in general case yes, but I use concrete case - say https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775071(v=vs.85).aspx - how understand this - "Return value

Type: HRESULT

If this method succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.
"

Comment: @IInspectable - for example `IDiaEnumSourceFiles::Next` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3dhdwwe.aspx - how here handle Return Value ? are SUCCEEDED and FAILED macros here can be used (even if we separate handle `S_FALSE`) ?

Comment: You **are** calling [CoInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx), which is documented to return success codes other than `S_OK`. Your trying to be clever only succeeded in making your code harder to read.

Comment: @IInspectable - look please again to my code - where I call `CoInitialize` I use `0 <= hr` condition - so no error here

Comment: @IInspectable - for specifics: 1)are can `SHGetKnownFolderIDList` return not S_OK but be successful ? (based on MSDN description) ? 2) how use `SUCCEEDED` and `FAILED` macros with say `IDiaEnumSourceFiles::Next` ? 3) if microsoft api (or inteface method) can return `S_FALSE` or `0 < hr` - are this always documented ? 4)can example show if not ?

Comment: I'm going to down-vote this proposed answer, solely for your stubbornness to accept, that readability is as much a requirement as correctness (and this isn't just about readability even). You can write all the clever code you want, for your own enjoyment. When publishing code on a Q&A site frequented by professionals, the rules are different.